# Angularjs ng-class binding

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Is it possible to combine a data-bind class and a conditional class in the same `ng-class` ?

Ex:

```
<div class="trow" ng-class="rowClass($index), data.accounts[k.id].checked ? 'checked' : '' " ng-repeat="k in accounts | filter:{location_id: location.id}">
```

This isn't working for me and neither

```
ng-class="{rowClass($index), data.accounts[k.id].checked ? 'checked' : '' }"
```

I want to have both classes, the data-binded `rowClass($index)` and also the conditional `data.accounts[k.id].checked ? 'checked' : ''` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array to combine the two:

```
ng-class="[rowClass($index), data.accounts[k.id].checked ? 'checked' : '' ]"
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-class Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).